# Cross Browser Circle Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, velocity.js

I'm attempting to make a Circle progress bar much like seen [here](http://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/).

This jQuery plugin does exactly what I want to be able to accomplish with the problem being that it isn't cross-browser as velocity.js is.

I have looked at other sources such as:

1. [example #1](http://codepen.io/julianshapiro/pen/IlJtC)
2. [example #2](http://codepen.io/ghepting/pen/xnezB)
3. [example #3](http://codepen.io/trhino/pen/DLtjy?editors=001)

   ```
    $("div").velocity(
       { 
         rotateZ: 360
       },
       { 
         easing: [ 60 ],
         duration: 30000
       });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Iam answering this because i have been after this problem , you should refer to this link if you are after cross browser solution :

http://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

HTML:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="340px" height="333px" viewBox="0 0 340 333" enable-background="new 0 0 340 333" xml:space="preserve">

  <path class="path" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8
    s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41
    C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z"/>      
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/bGyoz)

Also : Knob JS would be a good option

http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

```
<input type="text" value="75" class="dial">

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".dial").knob();
    });
</script>
```

check the example where you can use knob as timer.

Comment: Yes, I have been to that link before; I couldn't figure out how that would be used to demonstrate a percentage on a circle, would you mind elaborating further?

Comment: @MarkTHarris depending on what you are trying to achieve , using animate keyframes + less or sass , you can do it http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation3

Comment: @MarkTHarris you can use JS to calculate your percent and send the value to be the keyframe value.

Comment: @MarkTHarris also check knob.js

Comment: Hmm I have seen knob.js before and it seems like it would work, but how would you do it using css and animated keyframes? That seems like a much cleaner way to do it.

Comment: I might also note the reason I'm wanting to stay with velocity and steer away from other jQuery plugins is due to it being used later in the webpage and I want to keep this as small as possible.

Comment: Unless, I just had an idea; Would it be possible to programmically modify the duration of the animation in order to display a certain percentage.

Comment: @MarkTHarris yes indeed just specify what you wanna do exactly and your restrictions , and i will help you.